# Component Identification tag merge

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup

When searching up on the tags, I found that there were [identification](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) and [component-identification](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/component-identification). Shouldn't [component-identification](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/component-identification) be merged into [identification](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) as it already fulfills that question type?

Comment: +1 for your original title, @Bradman175

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a no-brainer ... Done!